# How to tell how may unique elements there are an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I've got an array (actually a mutable array) of NSStrings, and I want to find out how many unique elements the are in the array.

For instance, say the array is made up of:

```
Orange, Lemon, Lemon, Orange, Lemon
```

Then there are just **two** unique elements (Orange and Lemon). And this array:

```
Paul, Steve, John, Harry, Paul, John
```

..has **four** unique unique elements.

How do I discover this number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSSet` can't contain equal objects, so the following works:

```
NSUInteger count = [[NSSet setWithArray:array] count];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a linear scan of the array, and, for each element, add it to an NSMutableSet.
Finally count the number of elements in the NSMutableSet. The NSMutableSet will not allow adding  a repeated element.

This is faster then sorting the array, and then doing  a linear scan incrementing a variable each time you discover a new element.

EDIT: the implementation in Objective-C has been provided by JoostK.

Answer (score 0):

```c
NSUInteger count = [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"] count];
```